# How to handle if statement inside a while loop - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, pyautogui

I am creating a game bot for my own game,  here in this(attached image is down bellow) game this stick man turns and turns away itself randomly.in the meantime I can use the  click button to steal his money if he turns while you are clicking on the button, game will be over.

what I am trying to perform is, taking x,y value of its forehead and and the pixel R value of RGB using **pyautogui**  library and if it matches R value of its forehead I would perform a mouse click. and same if it doesn't.

> The problem I get is, when I tried to run the following script it runs perfectly but the mouse click event is fired more than one time.

```
    import keyboard
    import pyautogui
    
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        if pyautogui.pixel(687, 144)[0] != 255:
            print("Looking at you")
            pyautogui.click(681, 662)
        else:
            print("Not looking at you")
            pyautogui.click(681,662)
```

> I tried the upon script with bool variables in the  following way, but it will only work onetime for both **Looking at you**  & **Not looking at you** once these variables become false the program doesn't work after.

```
    import keyboard
    import pyautogui
    
    
    boolval1=True
    boolval2=True
    
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        if pyautogui.pixel(687, 144)[0] != 255:
            if boolval1:
                print("Looking at you")
                pyautogui.click(681, 662)
                boolval1 = False
        else:
            if boolval2:
                print("Not looking at you")
                pyautogui.click(681,662)
                boolval2 = False
```

is there anyway I can perform only a single click every time this stick man turns and turns away??

here I have attached a sketch of the game to get a brief idea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    a = True
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    b = False
    if pyautogui.pixel(687, 144)[0] == 255:
        b = True
    if b != a:
        print("Click")
    a = b
```

I was able to find an answer this might save ones time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your code in an infinite loop

```
while True:
    # do stuff with is pressed and clicks
```

Just a piece of advice but i think you should look up the MVC design pattern,
this will be a mess to understand after :

```
        if pyautogui.pixel(687, 144)[0] != 255:
```

Comment: I don't deal with any data exchange to use MVC, while True:  is what I did use upon